# Python: Adding Variable paths into os.system("open"+filename)

Tags: python, file, list

I'm trying to make a script where python goes through a directory, finds all files that ends with *ref.SDAT, and then opens them all.

So far, I have the sorting of files process. The wanted files are put into reflist:

```
import os
import glob
import subprocess

os.chdir("/Users/BabyJ/Desktop/MRSDATA")
reflist = glob.glob('*raw_ref.SDAT')

print "These are the ref files:"
for i in reflist:
     os.system('open+%s') %i
```

I don't know how to structure the syntax so that os.system will open all of the components of the list though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming judging from your use of `open` that you are on a Mac or Unix system.  If that is the case use either of the following to get you up and running.

```
for i in reflist:
    os.system('open ' + '%s' % i)
```

or:

```
for i in reflist:
    subprocess.call('open ' + '%s' % i, shell = True)
```

Using subprocess is the better solution as os.system is, though not technically gone from the language, deprecated in Python per the official documentation.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

If you're using windows sub in `start` for `open`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator wants the `'open+%s'` string as its left-hand side. You are offering it the return value of `os.system()`. Also, I think you wanted a space, not a `+` in the string.

Try this:

```
os.system('open %s'%i)
```